# How to restart the GPIO after shutdown() called

Tags: pi-3, gpio, pi4j

After I call the following Java code:

```
gpio.shutdown()
```

The GPIO turns off.
How can I restart it?

I need to restart it because of [this problem](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/88653/provisiondigitaloutputpin-sets-mode-to-high-low-and-blink-dont-work/88691#88691). In the problem the light does not turn off with `led.low()` so I plan to turn it off by turning off the GPIO to turn off the light.

After I shutdown the GPIO when I call provisionDigitalOutputPin a second time to start the LED, it works.

Then I try to shutdown the GPIO again and it doesn't work.

How can I shutdown the GPIO multiple times in my program?

I am using a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B.

Comment: My best guess is that you have wired up the LED wrong.  The end result is you are now trying to solve a silly problem.  You would be best off showing one or more clear photos of your wiring.  We could then address the real problem.

Comment: @joan The led does light up when I call provisionDigitalOutputPin so it is connected.

Comment: If you want real help you need to provide photos of your wiring.  We do not know what you have done wrong - but you have done something wrong.

Comment: you need to solve the `because of this problem`  ... i added a comment to that post

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth - when I run into a software snag during development I just use hardware "/reset" (RPi labels the header differently) or software "reboot".

Little drastic, but gets me back to coding in known state.